# Variable column data depending on parameters

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an ad hoc report for a user that should allow them to select a table name from a database and then based on that table name it shows the column names that they select to have shown.

I have the parameters in place and working and can get the column headers to display based on the selection but cannot get the data to display on the tablix.

Please see my question in MSDN as i cannot post pictures here yet.

[My Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9a65b095-c623-4501-bfbf-f06bb3001f4c/tablix-data-mapping-based-on-parameters-selected?forum=sqlreportingservices)

```
DECLARE @Column_Name VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql_str VARCHAR(500)

SET @Column_Name = 'Id,Sort,Brand'
SET @Table_Name = 'Item'

SET @sql_str = 'Select ' + @Column_Name + ' FROM ' + @Table_Name 
--SELECT @sql_str

EXECUTE (@sql_str)
```

Comment: Is your report generating SQL that returns results?

Comment: Right now i have created a query that works in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make your query dynamically in SSRS. However, in SSRS, it need to fetch the metadata from the result set as data fields so that they can be rendered in tablix. In this scenario, since your result set is dynamic, it can get the fixed data field. So it can never be displayed in report body.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. The project got turned into an app.